# The term "per month" in reCAPTCHA pricing is calendar month or 30 days successively?

Tags: recaptcha

E.g. reCaptcha said *"If you wish to make more than 1000 calls per second or **1000000 calls per month**"*

**"per month"** here is calendar month (e.g. July 1 - July 31) or 30 days successively calculated from the 1st call (e.g. July 20 - Aug 20). If anyone knows, please help me to clear

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the [Enterprise pricing](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/pricing), it is clearly stating

> These prices are based on your monthly usage, determined at the end of each month